# Post sorting issues in WordPress using Twig/Timber

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming, timber

So we have a custom Wordpress Pet Site in which we sort pet posts by the ACF field of **litter_born** and it all works fine until no posts show and then it will just throw a page error.
Here is the code we are using:

```
{% for post in posts | sort((a, b) => b.litter_born <=> a.litter_born) %}
//pulling in post data
{% endfor %}
```

Which works fine until no posts show then it throws and error:

[image]

Comment: Did you try the filter `default` to catch the `null` values? `{% for post in posts|default([]) | sort .....`

Comment: I pref, do logic in your PHP class/functions it is not the true way on views.

Answer (score -1):

Wow, that's quite a bit of logic you got there in that loop filter! I think it's as simple as adding a conditional to ensure that posts has a length. Based on the error, sort requires a Traversable and doesn't itself have logic to gracefully handle a NULL

Comment: would you mind sharing a sample of your updated code in your answer - I had no success with if statements all?